# Are the dimensions of arrays max 2 that be created with np.arange?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new in NumPy. While i was reading the NumPy User Guide and making examples , i saw an example that made me to ask a question.

For example Python gave the below results:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(6)
>>> a.ndim
1
>>> b = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
>>> b.ndim
2
>>> c = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
>>> c.ndim
2
```

I expected that c.ndim would given 3 rather than 2. So my question is, are the max dimension sizes of arrays are 2 when these arrays are created with np.arange() function?

Comment: So, what do you think `ndim` denotes?

Comment: The number of dimensions (rank) of arrays?

Comment: So, why should `c.ndim` be `3`? I think you have misunderstood the concept of dimensions in NumPy array terms. See if this helps - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

Comment: Perhaps i have misunderstood, i am going to look at the page. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, it seems i asked an unnecessary  question before read the full document.

Answer (score 2):

What you are actually doing is first creating a 1D array with [arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) then [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) it.

```
a = np.arange(20) # of dimension 1
a = a.reshape(4,5)
print(a.ndim) # returns 2 because the array became a 2D 4x5
a = a.reshape(2,5,2)
print(a.ndim) # returns 3 because the array becomes a 3D 2x5x2
```

to summarize, you are forcing a reshape of a 1D np.array to a 2D using the reshape method, add more arguments to access more dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, i got it.